# USB drive accessible from Ubuntu laptop but can't find on OSX using Disk Utility or `df``

Tags: hard-drive, usb, unix

I have a 3T SATA hard drive in a USB enclosure. I can see it when I connect to my Ubuntu laptop, but I can't get it to be seen on my OSX desktop. My goal is to format from my Mac.

I've tried giving it different style partition tables (dos, gpt, mac) and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

- `df -h` does not show the drive when it's plugged in.
- `tail -f /var/log/system.log` does not show any change when I (up)plug the USB drive
- Disk Utility does not show the drive

Any ideas of what I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it had something to do with the (older) enclosure. I tried a different enclosure and it's working fine now.

The enclosure the did not work was an "iMicro(tm) 3.5" SATA&IDE HDD Combo Enclosure"